# Pytorch 1.6.0 - RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered where (predicted==labels)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

When I run this function:

```
def evaluate(model, dataloader, calc_loss=False):
'''
Helper function to get classification accuracy and (optional) loss for a model over the items in dataloader
This function can just return the accuracy, or calculate the losses if "calc_loss" is set to "True"
'''
correct = 0
total = 0
losses = []

# don't compute gradients
with torch.no_grad():
    for batch in dataloader:
        
        inputs, labels = batch
        # forward pass through the model
        outputs = model(inputs)
        print('pass 1')
        # calculate loss if parameter set to True
        if (calc_loss==True):            
            loss = F.cross_entropy(outputs, labels)   # Calculate loss
            losses.append(loss.detach)
        
        # Get the prediction of the net on the images
        print('pass 2')
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, dim=1)
        total += labels.size(0)

        # Count those we got correct
        right = torch.sum(predicted==labels).item()
        
        print('pass 3', right)
        break
        
    # calculate total correct cases
    acc = 100 * correct / total
return losses, acc
```

Here is what i plug in and get back:

```
evaluate(model_1, dataloader=val_dl, calc_loss=True)
```

Results:

> ```
> pass 1
> pass 2
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-22-881e9c4f2402> in <module>
>       1 os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = '1'
> ----> 2 evaluate(model_1, dataloader=val_dl, calc_loss=True)
>
> <ipython-input-15-edcb180f1931> in evaluate(model, dataloader, calc_loss)
>      29 
>      30             # Count those we got correct
> ---> 31             right = torch.sum(predicted==labels).item()
>      32 
>      33             print('pass 3', right)
>
> RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
> ```

It seems to be getting this error where the predict==labels are at, but when I run that code in isolation (outside of the for loop / function) it runs everything perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: change `loss.detach` to `loss.detach()`

Comment: Nevermind, turns out I just had the wrong number of outputs set on my model. I added a class but left it at the previous number of outputs. So whenever I ran pred==labels it would throw that error.